# How to fix Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart

Right now I'm working on the create profile page section. Which before coming to this page will verify the identity by using the otp code and will receive the token of the user as well in order to check whether this token has already applied to the system. If you haven't applied yet, you will come to the profile creation page. But if you have already applied, you can go straight to the main page.

But now I'm stuck with the problem that When pressing the confirm button on the profile creation page, this error occurs. where i want to fetch data from local storage which i have created sharedpreference to store and retrieve data already After that I created a model in response to the profiling, created the dio package used to build the network api in flutter, but I still can't find where it went wrong.

it's dio_client.dart

```
Future<ProfileUserResponseModel> createProfile({
  required String fullName,
  required String idLine,
  required String birthDate,
  required String? gender,
}) async {
  final request = ProfileUserRequestModel(
      fullName: fullName, idLine: idLine, birthDate: birthDate, gender: gender);
  final response =
      await dioToken().post(ApiConstants.createProfile, data: request.toJson());
  try {
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      return ProfileUserResponseModel.fromJson(response.data);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to create your profile');
    }
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    throw Exception(e);
  }
}
```

it's profile_*user_request*_model.dart

```
class ProfileUserRequestModel {
  ProfileUserRequestModel(
      {required this.fullName,
      required this.idLine,
      required this.birthDate,
      required this.gender});

  String fullName;
  String idLine;
  String birthDate;
  String? gender;

  factory ProfileUserRequestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ProfileUserRequestModel(
      fullName: json["full_name"],
      idLine: json["id_line"],
      birthDate: json["birth_date"],
      gender: json["gender"],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "full_name": fullName,
        "id_line": idLine,
        "birth_date": birthDate,
        "gender": gender,
      };
}
```

I think it may be caused by mistake getting gender variable from radio button. But I have already defined it as a string. But it can't be used. If anyone knows a way to fix the problem. Feel free to reply in the comments. Thank you very much.

Comment: your code looks fine, can you include where do you cakk this method

Comment: Please provide the code including the line, causing the error.